# How can I add Telosys repos as Maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency, jitpack, telosys

Im trying to add telosys as a maven dependency but Im enable to do it because its not published on Maven Central. I also tried to use jitpack but it doesnt work. Is there any way to do this?
Telosys Organization : https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks
Telosys repo there I am trying to use: https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-tools-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, indeed, for the time being Telosys API is not available on Maven Central as a ".jar" artefact.

So if you want to use the Telosys API to embed the generator into your own application, you have 2 possibilities :

1. the **classical way** : 
   **Build** the fat jar "telosys-tools-all-X.X.X.jar" (Telosys core) 
   **from the sources** using the root project "**telosys-tools-parent**" 
   https://github.com/telosys-tools-bricks/telosys-tools-parent 

   Maven dependencies (9 git repositories) :

   - telosys-tools-parent (multi-modules project)

     - telosys-tools-all ("all in one" fat jar)

       - telosys-tools-api (Telosys API with 6 dependencies)

         - telosys-tools-commons
         - telosys-tools-database
         - telosys-tools-repository
         - telosys-tools-dsl-parser
         - telosys-tools-generic-model
         - telosys-tools-generator
       - external dependencies (Velocity, etc)
2. the **fastest way** :

- dowload latest Telosys-CLI : https://www.telosys.org/download/telosys-cli
- unzip it
- add the "**telosys-cli-3.2.2-001.jar**" in your project dependencies 
  (this jar will be a little bigger, with unnecessary classes for your project but it will work)

Note : Telosys core will be available on Maven Central in future versions